# "Show deleted comments" function broken on some beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

The function "show x deleted comments" from the mod menu on posts is broken on some SE2.0 beta sites. In particular, it is returning an OOPS on Christianity.SE but not Hermeneutics.SE.

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.

This happens on all posts I've tried on both the main and meta sites.

Comment: Odd, it works on Workplace, which is also a beta site.

Comment: This just happened to me on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: [Obligatory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6PZhONZ3Ac)